# How can I make this kind of a border?

Tags: css, image, design-patterns, border

Do I have to use image to make this kind of... I don't even know how to explain it (my native language isn't english), but it's the transition from the top part to the darker part on this website:
http://thegregthompson.com/
. Do I **have** to use a image, or can I do this with not-to-overly-complicated-css? (Pseudo elements are fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the jagged edge/mini triangles, then for a simpler time you would be better recreating it the way they have using a repeating http://thegregthompson.com/wp-content/themes/GregThompson/assets/img/border-top.png.

I'm sure it would be possible in pure css, but it definitely wouldn't be 'not-to-overly-complicated' and my first thought is there would be a lot of unnecessary mark-up.

I hope this helps

Comment: Okay, I guess the best way is to use image. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, while [CSS triangles](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) are possible, a repeating row of them would require a repeating row of markup elements, as far as I can see. An image is the way to go, unless you're wanting to particularly showcase extreme CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use an image. You could probably do some advanced Javascript in a canvas element, but it's the long, hard and unnecessary way.

The site uses [this image](http://thegregthompson.com/wp-content/themes/GregThompson/assets/img/border-top.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's what they are using:

```
.sub_hold_top {
    height: 10px;
    background-image: url('../img/border-top.png');
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

**[Full path of Image](http://thegregthompson.com/wp-content/themes/GregThompson/assets/img/border-top.png)**

Comment: I know what they were using, but is there a way of doing this plain css? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: I wouldn't say that impossible but that will not be easy. As @kapser said `it's the long, hard and unnecessary way.`

Comment: @Schart it may be possible with the :before and :after pseudo elements, but it won't be at all easy.